# Understanding signatures in alloy

Tags: alloy

I read in the alloy website that a signature defines a set. Given this definition, I was trying to understand the below alloy code:

```
enum dooroptype { unlocked, locked, opened}
enum enginetype {on,off}
enum motortype { ismoving, still}
enum key_location { in_car, faralone}

abstract sig state{
  inside,far, near : set Person,
  car_action : motortype,
  engine : enginetype,
  key_position : (Person + key_location),
  door : dooroptype
}
```

If a signature actually defines a set, then why do we have so many parameters in the signature definiton as a set is a unary relation? If I am wrong, how does one interpret this definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking my first steps in Alloy, but I'll try to answer. This is what you have in the above code:

1. dooroptype = set (unary relation) with exactly 3 atoms.
2. enginetype = set (unary relation) with exactly 2 atoms.
3. motortype = set (unary relation) with exactly 2 atoms.
4. key_location = set (unary relation) with exactly 2 atoms.
5. state = set (unary relation) with 0 or more atoms.
6. inside, far and near = binary relations defined as `state -> set Person`
7. car_action = binary relation defined as `state -> one motortype`
8. engine = binary relation defined as `state -> one enginetype`
9. key_position = a union of two binary relations `state -> Person` and `state -> key_location` (but with multiplicity that constrains each state to appear at most once, so a state can be associated with either a `Person` or a `key_location`, but not with both)
10. door = binary relation defined as `state -> dooroptype`

In short, everything defined above is a relation, some are unary, some are binary. The binary relations `inside, far and near` are defined with `set` multiplicity, while all the others are defined with a multiplicity of one.

In other words, a signature is a set, and relations are defined inside the signatures, but are visible globally.

Comment: How do you know that car_action is a binary relation with state-> one motortype. Can you point me to the documentation of alloy where they cover this?

Comment: Alloy reference at http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/book-chapters/alloy-language-reference.pdf page 276 paragraph starting with "The multiplicity keywords apply cardinality constraints..."

Comment: Broken link in my comment above should be now: http://alloytools.org/download/alloy-language-reference.pdf (page 18 in the PDF, 276 as typed on the page)

Answer (score 2):

Two small corrections:

1. Technically speaking, enum enginetype {on,off} is short for

   ```
   sig enginetype {}
   one sig on, off extends engine type {}
   ```

so it declares 3 sets, two of which (on and off) are singletons.

1. The declaration of the field key_position in

   ```
   abstract sig state{
     key_position : (Person + key_location)
     }
   ```

can indeed be viewed as a union of two relations (over state -> Person and state -> key_location), but the multiplicity constraint is that there is exactly one value of s.key_position for any state s, not two values which Aviad's formulation suggests.

Comment: I agree that there is exactly one value for s.key_position. However, is it true that the value can either be a Person or a location?

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I didn't realize that until you said it.